# .jpg img white background clashes with html page white background

Tags: html, jpeg

My site uses a .jpg jpeg image as the top-of-page image on all pages of the site.  The image was created with a white background.  But using the **img src="topOfEveryPageImage.jpg"**  tag shows that the image's white background is visually different from the rest of the solid white background of the browser page.  The 'white' of the image is noticeable and not the same as the white of the browser page.

Yet the image was created on the very same computer using a .jpg authoring program.   And in the .jpg authoring tool, the image's white background looks like solid white and identical to the white of the browser window if I launch the browser on the same computer.

Is the "img" html tag interfering with the .jpg background color?  Here is the actual code:

```
<a href="mysite/landingPage.php">
   <img src="mysite/images/topOfEveryPageImage.jpg"
   alt="mysite/images/topOfEveryPageImage.jpg"
   </img>
</a>
```

Comment: Could you show us the image? Because no, the img tag is not interfering with the jpg background color :). Maybe you saved at a too low resolution.

Comment: you havent closed the opening image tag. also why are you closing the image tag in a seperate tag?

Comment: This is how you use the `img` tag: `<img src="mysite/images/topOfEveryPageImage.jpg"
   alt="Some actually useful description of the image" />`

Comment: yep the browser (Firefox) let me get away with the extra '<' on the closing '</img>' tag, changing to simply '/img>' to close the opening <img src=   tag made no difference (on Firefox).  Thanks.

Comment: Yuri I'm not sure how to load and show an image in the forum here, otherwise instead of this comment I would show you the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of those "whites" actually isn't `#ffffff`, then. Most image editing programs allow you to specify the color using this format; use the same color that your page's background uses.

Alternately, the image might have an embedded color profile, where the image's "white" could be visually very different from the webpage's notion of "white" - in that case, remove the color profile before using the image for the web.

Comment: The .jpg img was created in the Windows (Vista) 'Paint' program and there doesn't seem to be a way to control the resolution or color palette of the saved image, or is there?

Comment: Try saving as a .gif image. It uses a different compression algorithm that in this case wouldn't change the colors. Obviously, you won't be using a .jpg then but I don't think that is a problem?

Comment: Phortuin that did it thanks -- I did a 'Save As' in Paint and saved it as a .gif and now the image's background exactly matches the browser backround -- I'm not sure if that means I actually have a 'transparent' background saved with the image, I guess I'd have to check different browsers or change the background color for my browser to see that.

Comment: UPDATE: I changed my browser background color but the image background is still white.  Guess I need to create my site's images with an image creation program that allows saving a 'transparent' background with the image, otherwise -- if the user changes his browser's background color, my site will look bad.

Answer (score 0):

JPEG is a lossy format that cannot reproduce original colors accurately. Normally you wouldn't have the JPEG and the original shade for side-by-side comparison, and wouldn't notice the difference.

You should use the PNG format whenever the colors need to match. Or better yet, use alpha transparency and you'll be able to change webpage color without modifying the image at all.

Notice that the PNG format is best suited for screenshots, simple button/layout graphics and such, where there are large solid surfaces or even gradients, with no random noise. If the image contains photographs or other similar material, PNG won't compress very well and you get a large file. If the picture has been previously compressed in JPEG format, it is eternally ruined and needs to be recreated (or at least thoroughly cleaned up in an image editor) before saving as PNG to gain any of the PNG format benefits (otherwise it'll only take up more space than the original JPEG).